# tomcat8 spring-boot war memory leak

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat8

I have an application that is working on tomcat8 , on repeated undeploy/deploy (i use [parallel versions](https://objectpartners.com/2012/04/17/tomcat-v7-parallel-deployment/)) i noticed that the server memory increase also on tomacat manager clicking on find leaks shows the below

> The following web applications were stopped (reloaded, undeployed),
>   but their classes from previous runs are still loaded in memory, thus
>   causing a memory leak (use a profiler to confirm): /

i tried to use profiler to check what is still in memory but could not figure out , as i did not know where to start with .

stopping the application show the below log

```
2016-11-03 05:50:25.388 [               ]  INFO 29986 --- [http-nio-8080-exec-34] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.teltacworldwide.co].[/]    : Destroying Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2016-11-03 05:50:25.392 [               ]  INFO 29986 --- [http-nio-8080-exec-34] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.teltacworldwide.co].[/]    : Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
2016-11-03 05:50:25.393 [               ]  INFO 29986 --- [http-nio-8080-exec-34] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Closing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@7fe83fea: startup date [Wed Nov 02 15:09:26 GMT 2016]; root of context hierarchy
2016-11-03 05:50:25.403 [               ]  INFO 29986 --- [http-nio-8080-exec-34] o.s.c.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor  : Stopping beans in phase 2147483647
2016-11-03 05:50:25.411 [               ]  INFO 29986 --- [http-nio-8080-exec-34] o.s.m.s.s.StompBrokerRelayMessageHandler : Stopping...
2016-11-03 05:50:25.412 [               ]  INFO 29986 --- [http-nio-8080-exec-34] o.s.m.s.s.StompBrokerRelayMessageHandler : BrokerAvailabilityEvent[available=false, StompBrokerRelay[192.168.70.149:61613]]
2016-11-03 05:50:25.465 [               ]  WARN 29986 --- [globalEventExecutor-1-2] io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel         : Can't invoke task later as EventLoop rejected it

java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: event executor terminated
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.reject(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:715) ~[netty-all-4.0.31.Final.jar:4.0.31.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.addTask(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:300) ~[netty-all-4.0.31.Final.jar:4.0.31.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.execute(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:691) ~[netty-all-4.0.31.Final.jar:4.0.31.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.invokeLater(AbstractChannel.java:826) [netty-all-4.0.31.Final.jar:4.0.31.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.access$800(AbstractChannel.java:378) [netty-all-4.0.31.Final.jar:4.0.31.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe$5.run(AbstractChannel.java:571) [netty-all-4.0.31.Final.jar:4.0.31.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.GlobalEventExecutor$TaskRunner.run(GlobalEventExecutor.java:233) [netty-all-4.0.31.Final.jar:4.0.31.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:137) [netty-all-4.0.31.Final.jar:4.0.31.Final]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_45]
```

Comment: How can you do undeploy/deploy parallelly ? am I missing something ?

Comment: i mean tomcat [parallel deployment](https://objectpartners.com/2012/04/17/tomcat-v7-parallel-deployment/) as how i do it i use maven tomcat7 plugin